# Form submission using jQuery Mobile 1.4.2 remote autocomplete listview?

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-validate, jquery-mobile-listview

I have a form that contains several fields, including a remote autocomplete field using a `<ul data-role="listview">` like the jQuery Mobile 1.4.2 documentation states. In the desktop view, I'm using an `<input>` field with jQuery UI autocomplete. I'm getting jQuery validate errors on the `<ul>` mobile autocomplete field because the `<input>` field created by jQM doesn't contain the value. I'm using MVC 5 with unobstrusive validation by the way.

This is the jQuery Mobile HTML code I'm using:

```html
<div data-role="page" id="myPage">
    <div id="myFormDiv" class="ui-content" data-theme="a" role="main">
        <form id="myForm" method="post" data-ajax="False" action="/MyController/SetVal">
            <div class="validation-summary-errors">
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="myInput">
                                <ul id="field1" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true"></ul>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" id="done" name="btnSubmit" value="Done" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-theme="a" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm handling the form POST myself via JS like this:

```js
$.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serializeArray()) // ... code snipped
```

I see that the form data for **field1** does not appear, since the `<input>` field created by jQM for the `<ul>` tag does not contain a value attribute.

Is it possible to do a form submission using jQM 1.4 remote autocomplete listview?

Comment: You're going to have to show some code.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Sparky I've added code samples and an answer. Can you upvote me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by putting a hidden `<input>` below the `<td class="myInput">` tag and setting the value of that hidden input when the listview item is selected.